# Proving $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{J(n)}{n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Was hoping to get some feedback (either positive or negative) on my solution to the problem below. I don't really have anyone to bounce ideas off of and I'm trying to build my intuition for these kinds of problems.

**Problem**

$J(n) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } n \equiv 0 \mod3 \\
  1 & \mbox{if } n \equiv 1 \mod3 \\
        -1 & \mbox{if } n \equiv 2 \mod3
 \end{array}
\right.$

Prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{J(n)}{n}$ diverges.

**Solution**

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Define a new sequence $b_n$ to be a subsequence of $a_n$ comprised only of the terms that have indices that are equivalent to 1 or 2 mod 3.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} \frac{J(n)}{n} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{m_1} \frac{1}{3n} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{m_2} (-1)^{n+1}b_n$

where $m_1$ is the number of natural numbers between 1 and m that are divisible by 3 and $m_2$ is the number of natural numbers that aren't divisible by 3 between 1 and m.

By the alternating series test, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m_2} (-1)^{n+1}b_n$ converges as $m\to\infty$. This means if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} \frac{J(n)}{n}$ converges as $m\to\infty$ then so does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m_1} \frac{1}{3n}$. But we know the latter doesn't converge because it's a multiple of the harmonic series.